# Disable Submit action after validation is successful

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using this plugin http://code.google.com/p/bvalidator/

```
 $('#vendorDetailsForm').bValidator();

 if ( $('#vendorDetailsForm').data('bValidator').isValid() ) {
     $("#addVendorsTabs").tabs('select', 4);
 }
```

The above logic is bind to a button that is nested inside vendorDetailsForm element, but i want to disable the submit action upon validation is successfull, and instead navigate to tab in index 4.

Currently it navigate to index 4, but then it submit the form!

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) is your best option, so it works more consistently across browsers.

```
$("#submit").submit(function(evt) {
    ...
    evt.preventDefault(); // prevent default behavior of the event, in this case form submission
    return false; // return false, just in case, but in theory is not necessary
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put a `return false` at the end of the function triggered by the `submit` button.

For e.g.

```
$("#submit").submit(function() {
    $('#vendorDetailsForm').bValidator();
    if ($('#vendorDetailsForm').data('bValidator').isValid()) {
        $("#addVendorsTabs").tabs('select', 4);
    }
    return false;
});​
```

Comment: from the documentation "example 7" http://karmela.fsb.hr/~bmauser/bvalidator/documentation.html#examples it seems putting the input element in a div will solve the problem, but i tried his code copy & paste example 7 it didn't work!!!! ???

Comment: anyone has the same problem with that plugin